# Primefaces 5.1 and Wildfly does not deploy

Tags: primefaces, wildfly

I'm migrating my Glassfish app to Wildfly and there seems to be a compatibility error with Primefaces 5.1 JSF and Wildfly's bundled version. When I go to deploy, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.VerifyError:     (class: org/primefaces/component/api/UIData, method: getDataModel signature: )Ljavax/faces/model/DataModel;) Incompatible argument to function
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
... 3 more
```

Has anyone else gotten this error? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of JSF is bundled with Wildfly?  afaik it's 2.2?

Comment: What if you roll back to 5.0? I haven't tested PF 5.1 yet sorry.

Comment: I did try that, and it had the same result.

Comment: What version of jsf did u have on glassfish also was it mojarra might be some of your code using different implementation

Comment: I'm using PrimeFaces 5.0 on WildFly 8.1.0 without problems. Could it be that an incompatible JSF API jar slipped into your WAR?

Comment: That could be it. I'll have to try it again when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer was the JSF API/Impl wasn't included as a dependency in the jboss-deployment-structure. This caused all sorts of linkage errors. Once I added the following to my deployment/subdeployments in the file, the application bootstrapped.

```
<dependencies>
        <module name="javax.faces.api" />
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" />
</dependencies>
```